# How do I render Greek characters in code chunks in Rmarkdown to pdf?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

I use Rmarkdown to write python code and knit to pdf file for some reason...

I want to use and display greek characters like lambda in my code.

e.g.

```
def function(X,Y,λ,h):
    # do stuff
    return w
```

With default engine, it shows error message as below:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character λ (U+03BB)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See report.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

If I change the latex engine to xelatex or lualatex, it can knit to a pdf but the greek character disappear. Like this:

```
def function(X,Y, ,h):
    # do stuff
    return w
```

Do folks have any idea how to address that? Really appreciate it if someone could help.

---

Edited: add a minimal reproducible example as asked by the comment.

````
---
title: "Minimal reproducible example"
date: "2022-11-08"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



```{python}
def function(X,Y,λ,h):
    # do stuff
    return w
```
````

Comment: With xelatex/lualatex you'll probably have to choose a font which does have these characters.

Comment: Can you add a [mre] of your rmarkdown file so we can see your header etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to choose a font which does have Greek letters. For example with Arial (using Arial here because many people have it installed, choose a nicer looking font if you have it):

````
---
title: "Minimal reproducible example"
date: "2022-11-08"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
  - \setmonofont{Arial}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



```{python}
def function(X,Y,λ,h):
    # do stuff
    return w
```
````

[image]